# What is the typical voltage used on jet airliners?

Tags: airliner, jet, electrical-system, battery

I have seen several parts that use 28 Volts DC, is this a standard for jet airliners (e.g., Airbuses and Boeings).

Comment: Additionally you may want to know what do the generators/batteries initially deliver, before conversion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll see all kinds of power on large aircraft - 28 VDC, 115 VAC 60 Hz (and likely 230 VAC 50 Hz), 115 VAC 400 Hz, 5 VDC (USB power in cockpic/pax seats), 230 VAC, and 270 VDC.

Here's a general idea of what the Boeing 787 Power Distribution System consists of:

[image: 787_elec]
([Source](http://hydraulics.thesetupwarrior.com/boeing-787-hydraulic-system))

Answer (score 5):

Airbus use 28V DC, largely for things like sensors etc., so the overall power usage on the DC system is quite low: As an example, the A350 has 4 Transformer Rectifier Units (TRUs) which convert AC to DC. 2 of them are designated as 'normal' and 2 as 'emergency'. Each one has a nominal power of about 300W. Total DC system usage is about 500W. 
.
Unfortunately I don't know about Boeing.

EDIT: Was curious - looks like Boeing use 28V DC as well - which makes sense, I expect Airbus used 28V DC on the A300 as that was the standard at the time, and just kept using it until today.

Comment: 28VDC was in use in aerospace applications already before the A300's introduction. For example, [Apollo used 28VDC](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20090016295.pdf) (see PDF pages 4, 6) and [Apollo Spacecraft Familiarization training material for course APC-118](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/ApolloSpacecrftSystmsFAM67.pdf) (see PDF page 152). At which point one would have to ask: Why *not* use what obviously works? Absent good reasons to change, one might just go with what's already used for similar purposes elsewhere in the industry.